# How to compare string or textbox value (is bigger than x but smaller than y) (in between of the 2 values)

Tags: java, string, compare

My app is writing inputStream to string, then string to textView.
Under that I controll my UI animations with if statements.
Now I don`t know how to make if statement:
if (BTtext => 100 && BTtext <=350)

Values from 100 to 350 are for seekbarposition adjustment. I also have other values that need to be ignored in that case.
I had tryed:

```
if(strInput > lowervol && strInput < uppervol) {
}
```

strInput is my inputStream. lowervol & uppervol are created as so:

```
    final static String lowervol = "99";
    final static String uppervol = "351";
```

If I do it like that I get:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
first type:  String
second type: String

error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
first type:  String
second type: String
```

How can this be done?
Thank you

Comment: You can't just compare strings with mathematical operators. You need to convert the strings into numbers (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: So you need to convert your input to a number (and handle any exceptions if somehow your input is not a number!!!) and you can just have lowervol and uppervol begin as integers (`final static int lowervol = 99;`) for example

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare actual strings with `>` or `<`. What you actually want to compare in your case is the number contained in the string, not the string itself.

For that, your constants should probably be stored as `int`:

```
static final int LOWER_VOL= 99;
static final int UPPER_VOL= 351;
```

And before comparison, your `strInput` should be converted to `int` aswell. Something like this:

```
int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(strInput); // parsing exceptions to be handled here
if(inputValue > lowervol && inputValue < uppervol) {
    // do stuff
}
```

When adapting the naming convention of the constants from above, the final snippet will look like this:

```
int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(strInput); // parsing exceptions to be handled here
if(inputValue > LOWER_VOL && inputValue < UPPER_VOL) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Just commenting that after renaming the `lowervol` and `uppervol` as constants (correctly so) the `if` statement should probably use the updated names (although I can see arguments both ways depending on if the first piece of advice was ignored for whatever reason).  Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @BeUndead Good point, thanks for that. I updated the answer and added the final snippet which uses the renamed constants.

Answer (score 1):

you must try integer value. Please try below.

```
Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I had just got it solved.

```
                                int potVal=Integer.parseInt(strInput);
                            if(potVal >= 100 && potVal <= 350) {
                                volumeSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeSlider);
                                volumeSlider.setProgress(potVal);
                            }
```